# Override equals() method only of a Java object

Tags: java, android, overriding, equals

I am developing an Android application which makes use of the [`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) object. This object is in the form of:

```
[SSID: __mynetwork__, BSSID: 00:0e:2e:ae:4e:85, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS], level: -69, frequency: 2457, timestamp: 117455824743]
```

How would I override only the `equals()` method without creating a customer class which extends it in order to compare only the `SSID`, `BSSID`, `capabilties`, `level` and `frequency` attributes only? In other words, in the `equals` method I want to eliminate the `timestamp` attribute, so that when I compare these two objects, the `equals()` method would return a `true` value:

```
[SSID: __mynetwork__, BSSID: 00:0e:2e:ae:4e:85, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS], level: -69, frequency: 2457, timestamp: 117455824743]
[SSID: __mynetwork__, BSSID: 00:0e:2e:ae:4e:85, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS], level: -69, frequency: 2457, timestamp: 117460312231]
```

**Note:** When I derive a customer class which extends `ScanResult` I get the following error when I try to implement a constructor: `The constructor ScanResult() is not visible`

Comment: Override it and don't provide a check on timestamp, simply leave it out.

Comment: Shall I create a custom class which extends the equals method?

Comment: The question was if I can override that method only without creating a new class which extends it

Comment: No, you cannot do that

Comment: What are you doing with the objects that requires the equals() override?

Comment: You have to use a derived class of ScanResult and override the equals() method .. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/a/15886194/1202462

Comment: But I cannot derive it since it implements an interface and when I try to extend it I get the error: `The constructor ScanResult() is not visible`

Comment: Check Again... http://stackoverflow.com/a/15886194/1202462

Answer (score 4):

You just have to implement it without checking the fields you want to ignore.  Don't forget to override the hashode() too.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((field1 == null) ? 0 : field1.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((field2 == null) ? 0 : field2.hashCode());
            ...etc
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ScanResult other = (ScanResult ) obj;
    if (field1 == null) {
        if (other.field1 != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!field1.equals(other.field1))
        return false;
    if (field2 == null) {
        if (other.field2 != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!field2 .equals(other.field2 ))
        return false;
        }
... etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the `ScanResult` class and only override the `equals()` method

```
class CustomScanResult extends ScanResult {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // ... custom logic ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your Overriden equals() Method....

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof ScanResult)) return false;

    if(!BSSID.equals(o.BSSID)) return false;
    if(!SSID.equals(o.SSID)) return false;
    if(!capabilities.equals(o.capabilities)) return false;
    if(frequency != o.frequency) return false;
    if(level != o.level) return false;

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now that the above solution not working, may I suggest:

```java
class ScanResultComparator {
    public static boolean equals(ScanResult a, ScanResult b){
        if(!a.BSSID.equals(b.BSSID)) return false;
        if(!a.SSID.equals(b.SSID)) return false;
        if(!a.capabilities.equals(b.capabilities)) return false;
        if(a.frequency != b.frequency) return false;
        if(a.level != b.level) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe if all of them should be in one "if" block.
e.g. if(!a.BSSID.equals(b.BSSID) || !a.SSID.equals(b.SSID) ... ){

Answer (score 0):

simple way use check all variables for true.
example:

```
public class FtpFile {

    public String host;
    public String port;
    public String fileName;
    public String path;
    public String username;
    public String password;

    /**
     * Override Equals()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        try {
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            FtpFile p = (FtpFile) o;
            return ((host.equals(p.host))
                    && (port.equals(p.port))
                    && (path.equals(p.path))
                    && (username.equals(p.username))
                    && (password.equals(p.password)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```