# Compare objects android

Tags: java, android, compare, equals

I'm writing an app and at some point I have to compare two arraylist or two objects, I defined a class called Article and wrote this code to compare two articles

```
    public boolean aredifferent(){

    Article art1 = new Article();
    art1.setBm(null);
    art1.setDesc("he");
    art1.setImagelink("www");
    art1.setLink("www");
    art1.setTitle("ti");

    Article art2 = new Article();
    art2.setBm(null);
    art2.setDesc("he");
    art2.setImagelink("www");
    art2.setLink("www");
    art2.setTitle("ti");
    boolean diff;
    if(art1.equals(art2)){
        diff = false;
    }else{
        diff = true;
    }


    return diff;

}
```

the problem I'm having that this method is returning true and I can't see why. any ideas? is there a different way to compare objects in android?

Thank you

Comment: read this page. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885991/override-equals-method-only-of-a-java-object

Answer (score 0):

Check how `equals()` is implemented for that class, best guess is that you haven't overridden the `equals()` method and it is relying on `Object` 's implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you haven't defined a custom "equals" method for your Article class? If so, the reason why `art1.equals(art2)` is always returning `false` is because the default `equal` method in Java works by checking if the two objects have the same address in memory.

Because you're creating two different `Article` instances, they will obviously not share the same memory address and so `equals` will always return `false`. You can test this by doing something like `art1.equals(art1)` -- in that case, your method *will* behave as expected.

To fix this, you need to override the `equals` method in the `Article` class and create a new version that explicitly checks against the fields in the Article class. (You should also probably define a custom version of `hashCode` that uses those same fields.)